# Help with intro to Java procedure call

Tags: java, call, procedure

I have a school project in Java assigned to do the following:

> Write an application to be used in a
>   college admission's office.   To be
>   admitted to this school, the student
>   must have either:   •A grade point
>   average of 3.0 or higher and an
>   entrance score of 60 or higher •An
>   entrance score of 85 or higher and any
>   grade point average   To make things
>   more user friendly, write some code to
>   do some error checking of the data.
>   That is, if the grade point average is
>   not between 0.0 and 4.0 or if the
>   entrance score is not between 0 and
>   100, then print an appropriate error
>   message to the screen telling the user
>   that they entered invalid data.   Use
>   the above criteria to write a
>   procedure called, accepted, that takes
>   the grade point average and entrance
>   score as parameters and returns no
>   value.   This procedure will print
>   either "Accept" or "Reject",
>   accordingly. Finally, write a main
>   procedure that prompts the user for a
>   grade point average and an entrance
>   score.   This procedure should then
>   call the accepted method to display
>   the result.

Although I foolishly wrote the following code below without thoroughly reading the directions. My problem is I am not sure how call a procedure. Also how do I pass variables to this called procedure? Any help or other examples would be helpful. Below is the code I written while it works it doesn't feature an Accept procedure that gets called.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class College {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         double testGPA;
         int testScore;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Student Admisions");
        System.out.println("Please student prospects GPA: ");
        testGPA = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Now enter prospect students Test Score: ");
        testScore = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("-----------------------");

        if (testGPA >= 0.0 && testGPA <= 4.0 && testScore >= 0 && testScore <= 100){
            if(testGPA >= 3.0 && testScore >= 60 || testScore >= 85){
                System.out.println("Student is ACCEPTED to university!");
                System.out.println("Students GPA is a " + testGPA + " and students test score is a " + testScore + "%");
                }
            else {
                System.out.println("Student is NOT ACCEPTED to university!");
                System.out.println("Students GPA is a " + testGPA + " and students test score is a " + testScore + "%");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please Check GPA and Test score input!");
            System.out.println("Your inputs were:");
            System.out.println(testGPA + " = GPA should be between 0.0 and 4.0.");
            System.out.println(testScore + " = Test Score should be between 0 and 100");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm somewhat sceptical of an assignment which requires you to write a "procedure" in Java (rather than a method, the normal terminology) but if you really don't know how to declare a method with parameters, I would *strongly* suggest that SO shouldn't be your starting point. Ask your teachers for help, or read a Java book from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple procedure call demo here.

```
public class Demo {
    private static void prn(int x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prn(2);
        prn(3);
    }
}
```

Got it?

Comment: You have spelled 'class' with capital c

Comment: I got it that really helps clear it up. Thanks so much. Done with my program and its working great now!